# Apache server getting two access every 5 seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, amazon-web-services

I have an issue about apache server which is my server getting two access from unknown source every 5 seconds (exactly 5 seconds). One rails app is working on apache and getting log on either on apache and rails log. Using amazon aws as server and o and used load balance to share access to two server under 1 domain address. But either of them access repeatly. 
Is there anything you know about this? (Sorry about bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you allocate an Elastic IP it is drawn from AWS pool of available addresses, and there is a chance it was used in the past, so it is not unusual to see traffic coming from bots, crawlers, old clients, etc...

Comment: After long time searching my co-worker wrote a small pro in a batch server to check is load balancer working and forgot its still running. By the way thank for your reply.